# Activator.CreateInstance Performance Alternative

Tags: c#, .net, performance, reflection

I'm using RedGate to do some performance evaluation.  I notice dynamically creating an instance using `Activator.CreateInstance` (with two constructor parameters) is taking a decent amount of time... is there a better alternative that still utilizes a reflective approach (not explicit instantiation)?

Comment: I provided an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16162809/661933) for default instance.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use a compiled lambda if you can, its MUCH faster.

https://vagifabilov.wordpress.com/2010/04/02/dont-use-activator-createinstance-or-constructorinfo-invoke-use-compiled-lambda-expressions/

Comment: +1.  If that's still not fast enough then you might try reflection emit, but that's unlikely to yield much improvement over a compiled lambda, and it is a LOT more complicated to code.

Comment: Is the Compile() operation slower or faster? I am assuming the performance is accounted without including the compile time? In scenarios where multiple instances of different types are necessary and where type of object is determined at runtime, Would it be lot slower having compile operation everytime than Activator.CreateInstance?

Comment: [**Compiled expression on MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345362(v=vs.110).aspx) and [reflection vs compiled expressions vs delegates performance comparision](http://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/2012/2/4/reflection-vs-compiled-expressions-vs-delegates-performance-comparision)

Comment: @47d_ I believe you are right. I just did some testing, and while it is possible I made horrible mistake, it does look like compilation eats up most resources now. Even more than Activator.

Comment: @user1561358 the initial compile times for a lambda will be much slower than quite a few `Activator.CreateInstance()` calls, but you need to hold onto and reuse that same lambda throughout the process to see any useful performance boost and only if you call that lambda hundreds of times.  As always, optimize where it is needed.  Infrequent calls will not benefit from this.  It would be nice if someone built a library that could automatically optimize based on call volume, but that may slow things down just for the profiling.  Can't win.  8-)

Answer (score 18):

Don't forget about [DynamicMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod.aspx)

Here's example how to create new instance thru default constructor

```
public static ObjectActivator CreateCtor(Type type)
{
    if (type == null)
    {
        throw new NullReferenceException("type");
    }
    ConstructorInfo emptyConstructor = type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
    var dynamicMethod = new DynamicMethod("CreateInstance", type, Type.EmptyTypes, true);
    ILGenerator ilGenerator = dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, emptyConstructor);
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    return (ObjectActivator)dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(ObjectActivator));
}

public delegate object ObjectActivator();
```

here's more about [performance comparison](http://devcenter.wintellect.com/krome/getting-to-know-dynamicmethod)

> Measuring InvokeMember... 1000000 iterations in 1.5643784 seconds.
>
> Measuring MethodInfo.Invoke... 1000000 iterations in 0.8150111 seconds.
>
> Measuring DynamicMethod... 1000000 iterations in 0.0330202 seconds.
>
> Measuring direct call... 1000000 iterations in 0.0136752 seconds.

Comment: this code throws exception when class or struct does not have a constructor specified i.e. `public MyClass()`. In most cases - this code is omitted, especially for DTOs. Would be nice to see this answer improved so that explicit constructor would not be a requirement.

Answer (score 9):

I have created a solution that can be used as a drop in replacement for `Activator.CreateInstance`. You can find it on my [blog](https://trenki2.github.io/blog/2018/12/28/activator-createinstance-faster-alternative/).

**Example:**

```
var myInstance = InstanceFactory.CreateInstance(typeof(MyClass));
var myArray1 = InstanceFactory.CreateInstance(typeof(int[]), 1024);
var myArray2 = InstanceFactory.CreateInstance(typeof(int[]), new object[] { 1024 });
```

**Code:**

```
public static class InstanceFactory
{
  private delegate object CreateDelegate(Type type, object arg1, object arg2, object arg3);

  private static ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<Type, Type, Type, Type>, CreateDelegate> cachedFuncs = new ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<Type, Type, Type, Type>, CreateDelegate>();

  public static object CreateInstance(Type type)
  {
    return InstanceFactoryGeneric<TypeToIgnore, TypeToIgnore, TypeToIgnore>.CreateInstance(type, null, null, null);
  }

  public static object CreateInstance<TArg1>(Type type, TArg1 arg1)
  {
    return InstanceFactoryGeneric<TArg1, TypeToIgnore, TypeToIgnore>.CreateInstance(type, arg1, null, null);
  }

  public static object CreateInstance<TArg1, TArg2>(Type type, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2)
  {
    return InstanceFactoryGeneric<TArg1, TArg2, TypeToIgnore>.CreateInstance(type, arg1, arg2, null);
  }

  public static object CreateInstance<TArg1, TArg2, TArg3>(Type type, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, TArg3 arg3)
  {
    return InstanceFactoryGeneric<TArg1, TArg2, TArg3>.CreateInstance(type, arg1, arg2, arg3);
  }

  public static object CreateInstance(Type type, params object[] args)
  {
    if (args == null)
      return CreateInstance(type);

    if (args.Length > 3 || 
      (args.Length > 0 && args[0] == null) ||
      (args.Length > 1 && args[1] == null) ||
      (args.Length > 2 && args[2] == null))
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance(type, args);   
    }

    var arg0 = args.Length > 0 ? args[0] : null;
    var arg1 = args.Length > 1 ? args[1] : null;
    var arg2 = args.Length > 2 ? args[2] : null;

    var key = Tuple.Create(
      type,
      arg0?.GetType() ?? typeof(TypeToIgnore),
      arg1?.GetType() ?? typeof(TypeToIgnore),
      arg2?.GetType() ?? typeof(TypeToIgnore));

    if (cachedFuncs.TryGetValue(key, out CreateDelegate func))
      return func(type, arg0, arg1, arg2);
    else
      return CacheFunc(key)(type, arg0, arg1, arg2);
  }

  private static CreateDelegate CacheFunc(Tuple<Type, Type, Type, Type> key)
  {
    var types = new Type[] { key.Item1, key.Item2, key.Item3, key.Item4 };
    var method = typeof(InstanceFactory).GetMethods()
                                        .Where(m => m.Name == "CreateInstance")
                                        .Where(m => m.GetParameters().Count() == 4).Single();
    var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { key.Item2, key.Item3, key.Item4 });

    var paramExpr = new List<ParameterExpression>();
    paramExpr.Add(Expression.Parameter(typeof(Type)));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      paramExpr.Add(Expression.Parameter(typeof(object)));

    var callParamExpr = new List<Expression>();
    callParamExpr.Add(paramExpr[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
      callParamExpr.Add(Expression.Convert(paramExpr[i], types[i]));

    var callExpr = Expression.Call(generic, callParamExpr);
    var lambdaExpr = Expression.Lambda<CreateDelegate>(callExpr, paramExpr);
    var func = lambdaExpr.Compile();
    cachedFuncs.TryAdd(key, func);
    return func;
  }
}

public static class InstanceFactoryGeneric<TArg1, TArg2, TArg3>
{
  private static ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, object>> cachedFuncs = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, object>>();

  public static object CreateInstance(Type type, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, TArg3 arg3)
  {
    if (cachedFuncs.TryGetValue(type, out Func<TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, object> func))
      return func(arg1, arg2, arg3);
    else
      return CacheFunc(type, arg1, arg2, arg3)(arg1, arg2, arg3);
  }

  private static Func<TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, object> CacheFunc(Type type, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, TArg3 arg3)
  {
    var constructorTypes = new List<Type>();
    if (typeof(TArg1) != typeof(TypeToIgnore))
      constructorTypes.Add(typeof(TArg1));
    if (typeof(TArg2) != typeof(TypeToIgnore))
      constructorTypes.Add(typeof(TArg2));
    if (typeof(TArg3) != typeof(TypeToIgnore))
      constructorTypes.Add(typeof(TArg3));

    var parameters = new List<ParameterExpression>()
    {
      Expression.Parameter(typeof(TArg1)),
      Expression.Parameter(typeof(TArg2)),
      Expression.Parameter(typeof(TArg3)),
    };

    var constructor = type.GetConstructor(constructorTypes.ToArray());
    var constructorParameters = parameters.Take(constructorTypes.Count).ToList();
    var newExpr = Expression.New(constructor, constructorParameters);
    var lambdaExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, object>>(newExpr, parameters);
    var func = lambdaExpr.Compile();
    cachedFuncs.TryAdd(type, func);
    return func;
  }
}

public class TypeToIgnore
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to change this slightly to use a string instead of type for the dictionary key. But it worked beautifully.

Comment: Thank you, very nice, clear code - nice idea to use this cache.

Comment: Absolutely wonderful piece of code.  The InstanceGenericFactory only uses the type to cache the items in the Concurrent dictionary.  Not sure if there is a possibility of this causing issues if the type has multiple constructors or constructors with default values.  I'm thinking it could potential be an issue...  I'm going to adapt this to use the type and all of the parameters that are not of type TypeToIgnore as my key in the dictionary...  Can I get a sanity check here?  Is this overkill/unnecessary?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a set of predefined methods that cover 1-16 parameters, here you go:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace YournamespaceHere;

public class Constructors<TKnownType>
{
    public static Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, TKnownType> New<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16>(Type t, BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    {
        if (t == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(t));
        if (!typeof(TKnownType).IsAssignableFrom(t)) throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(TKnownType)} cannot be assigned to from the type provided by {nameof(t)}.", nameof(t));
        var ctor = t.GetConstructor(bindingFlags, Type.DefaultBinder, new Type[] { typeof(T1), typeof(T2), typeof(T3), typeof(T4), typeof(T5), typeof(T6), typeof(T7), typeof(T8), typeof(T9), typeof(T10), typeof(T11), typeof(T12), typeof(T13), typeof(T14), typeof(T15), typeof(T16) }, null);
        if (ctor == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(null, nameof(t));
        var t1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T1), "t1");
        var t2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T2), "t2");
        var t3 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T3), "t3");
        var t4 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T4), "t4");
        var t5 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T5), "t5");
        var t6 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T6), "t6");
        var t7 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T7), "t7");
        var t8 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T8), "t8");
        var t9 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T9), "t9");
        var t10 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T10), "t10");
        var t11 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T11), "t11");
        var t12 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T12), "t12");
        var t13 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T13), "t13");
        var t14 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T14), "t14");
        var t15 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T15), "t15");
        var t16 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T16), "t16");
        var newExpression = Expression.New(ctor, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, t10, t11, t12, t13, t14, t15, t16);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, TKnownType>>(newExpression, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, t10, t11, t12, t13, t14, t15, t16).Compile();
    }
    public static Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, TKnownType> New<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15>(Type t, BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    {
        if (t == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(t));
        if (!typeof(TKnownType).IsAssignableFrom(t)) throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(TKnownType)} cannot be assigned to from the type provided by {nameof(t)}.", nameof(t));
        var ctor = t.GetConstructor(bindingFlags, Type.DefaultBinder, new Type[] { typeof(T1), typeof(T2), typeof(T3), typeof(T4), typeof(T5), typeof(T6), typeof(T7), typeof(T8), typeof(T9), typeof(T10), typeof(T11), typeof(T12), typeof(T13), typeof(T14), typeof(T15) }, null);
        if (ctor == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(null, nameof(t));
        var t1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T1), "t1");
        var t2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T2), "t2");
        var t3 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T3), "t3");
        var t4 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T4), "t4");
        var t5 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T5), "t5");
        var t6 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T6), "t6");
        var t7 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T7), "t7");
        var t8 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T8), "t8");
        var t9 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T9), "t9");
        var t10 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T10), "t10");
        var t11 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T11), "t11");
        var t12 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T12), "t12");
        var t13 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T13), "t13");
        var t14 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T14), "t14");
        var t15 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T15), "t15");
        var newExpression = Expression.New(ctor, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, t10, t11, t12, t13, t14, t15);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, TKnownType>>(newExpression, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, t10, t11, t12, t13, t14, t15).Compile();
    }
    public static Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, TKnownType> New<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14>(Type t, BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    {
        if (t == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(t));
        if (!typeof(TKnownType).IsAssignableFrom(t)) throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(TKnownType)} cannot be assigned to from the type provided by {nameof(t)}.", nameof(t));
        var ctor = t.GetConstructor(bindingFlags, Type.DefaultBinder, new Type[] { typeof(T1), typeof(T2), typeof(T3), typeof(T4), typeof(T5), typeof(T6), typeof(T7), typeof(T8), typeof(T9), typeof(T10), typeof(T11), typeof(T12), typeof(T13), typeof(T14) }, null);
        if (ctor == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(null, nameof(t));
        var t1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T1), "t1");
        var t2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T2), "t2");
        var t3 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T3), "t3");
        var t4 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T4), "t4");
        var t5 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T5), "t5");
        var t6 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T6), "t6");
        var t7 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T7), "t7");
        var t8 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T8), "t8");
        var t9 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T9), "t9");
        var t10 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T10), "t10");
        var t11 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T11), "t11");
        var t12 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T12), "t12");
        var t13 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T13), "t13");
        var t14 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T14), "t14");
        var newExpression = Expression.New(ctor, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, t10, t11, t12, t13, t14);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, TKnownType>>(newExpression, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, t10, t11, t12, t13, t14).Compile();
    }
    public static Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, TKnownType> New<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13>(Type t, BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    {
        if (t == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(t));
        if (!typeof(TKnownType).IsAssignableFrom(t)) throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(TKnownType)} cannot be assigned to from the type provided by {nameof(t)}.", nameof(t));
        var ctor = t.GetConstructor(bindingFlags, Type.DefaultBinder, new Type[] { typeof(T1), typeof(T2), typeof(T3), typeof(T4), typeof(T5), typeof(T6), typeof(T7), typeof(T8), typeof(T9), typeof(T10), typeof(T11), typeof(T12), typeof(T13) }, null);
        if (ctor == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(null, nameof(t));
        var t1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T1), "t1");
        var t2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T2), "t2");
        var t3 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T3), "t3");
        var t4 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T4), "t4");
        var t5 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T5), "t5");
        var t6 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T6), "t6");
        var t7 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T7), "t7");
        var t8 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T8), "t8");
        var t9 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T9), "t9");
        var t10 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T10), "t10");
        var t11 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T11), "t11");
        var t12 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T12), "t12");
        var t13 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T13), "t13");
        var newExpression = Expression.New(ctor, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, t10, t11, t12, t13);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, TKnownType>>(newExpression, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, t10, t11, t12, t13).Compile();
    }
    public static Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, TKnownType> New<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12>(Type t, BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    {
        if (t == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(t));
        if (!typeof(TKnownType).IsAssignableFrom(t)) throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(TKnownType)} cannot be assigned to from the type provided by {nameof(t)}.", nameof(t));
        var ctor = t.GetConstructor(bindingFlags, Type.DefaultBinder, new Type[] { typeof(T1), typeof(T2), typeof(T3), typeof(T4), typeof(T5), typeof(T6), typeof(T7), typeof(T8), typeof(T9), typeof(T10), typeof(T11), typeof(T12) }, null);
        if (ctor == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(null, nameof(t));
        var t1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T1), "t1");
        var t2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T2), "t2");
        var t3 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T3), "t3");
        var t4 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T4), "t4");
        var t5 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T5), "t5");
        var t6 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T6), "t6");
        var t7 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T7), "t7");
        var t8 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T8), "t8");
        var t9 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T9), "t9");
        var t10 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T10), "t10");
        var t11 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T11), "t11");
        var t12 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T12), "t12");
        var newExpression = Expression.New(ctor, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, t10, t11, t12);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, TKnownType>>(newExpression, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, t10, t11, t12).Compile();
    }
    public static Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, TKnownType> New<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11>(Type t, BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    {
        if (t == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(t));
        if (!typeof(TKnownType).IsAssignableFrom(t)) throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(TKnownType)} cannot be assigned to from the type provided by {nameof(t)}.", nameof(t));
        var ctor = t.GetConstructor(bindingFlags, Type.DefaultBinder, new Type[] { typeof(T1), typeof(T2), typeof(T3), typeof(T4), typeof(T5), typeof(T6), typeof(T7), typeof(T8), typeof(T9), typeof(T10), typeof(T11) }, null);
        if (ctor == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(null, nameof(t));
        var t1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T1), "t1");
        var t2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T2), "t2");
        var t3 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T3), "t3");
        var t4 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T4), "t4");
        var t5 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T5), "t5");
        var t6 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T6), "t6");
        var t7 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T7), "t7");
        var t8 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T8), "t8");
        var t9 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T9), "t9");
        var t10 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T10), "t10");
        var t11 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T11), "t11");
        var newExpression = Expression.New(ctor, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, t10, t11);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, TKnownType>>(newExpression, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, t10, t11).Compile();
    }
    public static Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, TKnownType> New<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10>(Type t, BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    {
        if (t == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(t));
        if (!typeof(TKnownType).IsAssignableFrom(t)) throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(TKnownType)} cannot be assigned to from the type provided by {nameof(t)}.", nameof(t));
        var ctor = t.GetConstructor(bindingFlags, Type.DefaultBinder, new Type[] { typeof(T1), typeof(T2), typeof(T3), typeof(T4), typeof(T5), typeof(T6), typeof(T7), typeof(T8), typeof(T9), typeof(T10) }, null);
        if (ctor == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(null, nameof(t));
        var t1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T1), "t1");
        var t2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T2), "t2");
        var t3 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T3), "t3");
        var t4 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T4), "t4");
        var t5 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T5), "t5");
        var t6 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T6), "t6");
        var t7 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T7), "t7");
        var t8 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T8), "t8");
        var t9 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T9), "t9");
        var t10 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T10), "t10");
        var newExpression = Expression.New(ctor, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, t10);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, TKnownType>>(newExpression, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, t10).Compile();
    }
    public static Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, TKnownType> New<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9>(Type t, BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    {
        if (t == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(t));
        if (!typeof(TKnownType).IsAssignableFrom(t)) throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(TKnownType)} cannot be assigned to from the type provided by {nameof(t)}.", nameof(t));
        var ctor = t.GetConstructor(bindingFlags, Type.DefaultBinder, new Type[] { typeof(T1), typeof(T2), typeof(T3), typeof(T4), typeof(T5), typeof(T6), typeof(T7), typeof(T8), typeof(T9) }, null);
        if (ctor == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(null, nameof(t));
        var t1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T1), "t1");
        var t2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T2), "t2");
        var t3 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T3), "t3");
        var t4 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T4), "t4");
        var t5 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T5), "t5");
        var t6 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T6), "t6");
        var t7 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T7), "t7");
        var t8 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T8), "t8");
        var t9 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T9), "t9");
        var newExpression = Expression.New(ctor, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, TKnownType>>(newExpression, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9).Compile();
    }
    public static Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, TKnownType> New<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8>(Type t, BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    {
        if (t == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(t));
        if (!typeof(TKnownType).IsAssignableFrom(t)) throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(TKnownType)} cannot be assigned to from the type provided by {nameof(t)}.", nameof(t));
        var ctor = t.GetConstructor(bindingFlags, Type.DefaultBinder, new Type[] { typeof(T1), typeof(T2), typeof(T3), typeof(T4), typeof(T5), typeof(T6), typeof(T7), typeof(T8) }, null);
        if (ctor == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(null, nameof(t));
        var t1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T1), "t1");
        var t2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T2), "t2");
        var t3 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T3), "t3");
        var t4 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T4), "t4");
        var t5 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T5), "t5");
        var t6 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T6), "t6");
        var t7 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T7), "t7");
        var t8 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T8), "t8");
        var newExpression = Expression.New(ctor, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, TKnownType>>(newExpression, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8).Compile();
    }
    public static Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, TKnownType> New<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7>(Type t, BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    {
        if (t == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(t));
        if (!typeof(TKnownType).IsAssignableFrom(t)) throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(TKnownType)} cannot be assigned to from the type provided by {nameof(t)}.", nameof(t));
        var ctor = t.GetConstructor(bindingFlags, Type.DefaultBinder, new Type[] { typeof(T1), typeof(T2), typeof(T3), typeof(T4), typeof(T5), typeof(T6), typeof(T7) }, null);
        if (ctor == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(null, nameof(t));
        var t1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T1), "t1");
        var t2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T2), "t2");
        var t3 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T3), "t3");
        var t4 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T4), "t4");
        var t5 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T5), "t5");
        var t6 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T6), "t6");
        var t7 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T7), "t7");
        var newExpression = Expression.New(ctor, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, TKnownType>>(newExpression, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7).Compile();
    }
    public static Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, TKnownType> New<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>(Type t, BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    {
        if (t == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(t));
        if (!typeof(TKnownType).IsAssignableFrom(t)) throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(TKnownType)} cannot be assigned to from the type provided by {nameof(t)}.", nameof(t));
        var ctor = t.GetConstructor(bindingFlags, Type.DefaultBinder, new Type[] { typeof(T1), typeof(T2), typeof(T3), typeof(T4), typeof(T5), typeof(T6) }, null);
        if (ctor == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(null, nameof(t));
        var t1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T1), "t1");
        var t2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T2), "t2");
        var t3 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T3), "t3");
        var t4 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T4), "t4");
        var t5 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T5), "t5");
        var t6 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T6), "t6");
        var newExpression = Expression.New(ctor, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, TKnownType>>(newExpression, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6).Compile();
    }
    public static Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, TKnownType> New<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>(Type t, BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    {
        if (t == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(t));
        if (!typeof(TKnownType).IsAssignableFrom(t)) throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(TKnownType)} cannot be assigned to from the type provided by {nameof(t)}.", nameof(t));
        var ctor = t.GetConstructor(bindingFlags, Type.DefaultBinder, new Type[] { typeof(T1), typeof(T2), typeof(T3), typeof(T4), typeof(T5) }, null);
        if (ctor == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(null, nameof(t));
        var t1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T1), "t1");
        var t2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T2), "t2");
        var t3 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T3), "t3");
        var t4 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T4), "t4");
        var t5 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T5), "t5");
        var newExpression = Expression.New(ctor, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, TKnownType>>(newExpression, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5).Compile();
    }
    public static Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, TKnownType> New<T1, T2, T3, T4>(Type t, BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    {
        if (t == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(t));
        if (!typeof(TKnownType).IsAssignableFrom(t)) throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(TKnownType)} cannot be assigned to from the type provided by {nameof(t)}.", nameof(t));
        var ctor = t.GetConstructor(bindingFlags, Type.DefaultBinder, new Type[] { typeof(T1), typeof(T2), typeof(T3), typeof(T4) }, null);
        if (ctor == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(null, nameof(t));
        var t1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T1), "t1");
        var t2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T2), "t2");
        var t3 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T3), "t3");
        var t4 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T4), "t4");
        var newExpression = Expression.New(ctor, t1, t2, t3, t4);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, TKnownType>>(newExpression, t1, t2, t3, t4).Compile();
    }
    public static Func<T1, T2, T3, TKnownType> New<T1, T2, T3>(Type t, BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    {
        if (t == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(t));
        if (!typeof(TKnownType).IsAssignableFrom(t)) throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(TKnownType)} cannot be assigned to from the type provided by {nameof(t)}.", nameof(t));
        var ctor = t.GetConstructor(bindingFlags, Type.DefaultBinder, new Type[] { typeof(T1), typeof(T2), typeof(T3) }, null);
        if (ctor == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(null, nameof(t));
        var t1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T1), "t1");
        var t2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T2), "t2");
        var t3 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T3), "t3");
        var newExpression = Expression.New(ctor, t1, t2, t3);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, T2, T3, TKnownType>>(newExpression, t1, t2, t3).Compile();
    }
    public static Func<T1, T2, TKnownType> New<T1, T2>(Type t, BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    {
        if (t == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(t));
        if (!typeof(TKnownType).IsAssignableFrom(t)) throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(TKnownType)} cannot be assigned to from the type provided by {nameof(t)}.", nameof(t));
        var ctor = t.GetConstructor(bindingFlags, Type.DefaultBinder, new Type[] { typeof(T1), typeof(T2) }, null);
        if (ctor == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(null, nameof(t));
        var t1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T1), "t1");
        var t2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T2), "t2");
        var newExpression = Expression.New(ctor, t1, t2);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, T2, TKnownType>>(newExpression, t1, t2).Compile();
    }
    public static Func<T1, TKnownType> New<T1>(Type t, BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    {
        if (t == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(t));
        if (!typeof(TKnownType).IsAssignableFrom(t)) throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(TKnownType)} cannot be assigned to from the type provided by {nameof(t)}.", nameof(t));
        var ctor = t.GetConstructor(bindingFlags, Type.DefaultBinder, new Type[] { typeof(T1) }, null);
        if (ctor == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(null, nameof(t));
        var t1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T1), "t1");
        var newExpression = Expression.New(ctor, t1);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, TKnownType>>(newExpression, t1).Compile();
    }
    public static Func<TKnownType> New(Type t, BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    {
        if (t == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(t));
        if (!typeof(TKnownType).IsAssignableFrom(t)) throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(TKnownType)} cannot be assigned to from the type provided by {nameof(t)}.", nameof(t));
        var ctor = t.GetConstructor(bindingFlags, Type.DefaultBinder, Type.EmptyTypes, null);
        if (ctor == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(null, nameof(t));
        var newExpression = Expression.New(ctor);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TKnownType>>(newExpression).Compile();
    }
}
```

I'm not including a definition of all 16 parameters with varied ref/out semantics because that would be 3<sup>16</sup>+3<sup>15</sup>...+3<sup>1</sup> methods **and** delegates. Adding it up is over 60 million methods/delegates.  I'm sure you can use the details from this post to craft your own.

Edit:
I forgot to mention this can be especially useful if you want to provide libraries that need to create specific types of type-parameters which go beyond the default .ctor (the `new` constraint).