# Activator.CreateInstance for create Ironpython class

Tags: c#, .net, instance, ironpython, activator

Is it possible to use `Activator.CreateInstance` to create a class in c# based on a Type declared in Ironpython? If I try to use it, I always get the message, that no parameter-less constructor is found.

Thank you!

Comment: @Veverke i don't get what you mean.

Comment: There is only one parameter-Less constructor, that is why i am so confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer, no it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Activator.CreateInstance has many overloads. You should use the overload which requires a Type and an adition object array for the attributes

You can create an instance of this class

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(int _int, string _string, bool _bool)
    {
    }
}
```

with

```
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyClass), new object[] { 1, "string", true });
```

As `die maus` said, Activator.CreateInstance may be slow compared to other solutions. But it totally depends what you want to do. If you want to build an Dependency Injection Framework I would suggest you use an alternatives approach. If you want to create a type at runtime and it does not matter if it takes 3 or 15 milliseconds you should be fine.

I wrote a quick benchmark:

```
        var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            var file = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"c:\temp\file");
        }
        var t1 = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        var args = new object [] { @"c:\temp\file" };
        sw.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            var file = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(System.IO.FileInfo), args);
        }
        var t2 = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine("t1: {0}", t1);
        Console.WriteLine("t2: {0}", t2);
```

Output:

```
t1: 466
t2: 1246
```

I would not consider this `huge` in most scenarios...

Comment: You can actually leave out `new object[] { 1, "string", true }` and just specify the arguments as... just that, since the `args`-argument is a `params`-parameter. `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyClass), 1, "string", true);`

Comment: Thank you, but: 1. i have NO Parameter. 2. the Performance does not metter. 3. i use dlr classes, which seems to be the problem

Comment: @BendEg - The error message `no parameter-less constructor is found` is pretty clear. Maybe you could post some example code or take a look at `type.GetConstructors()` to figure out what `.ctors` your class has.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you use the overload of `Activator.CreateInstance` only takes the `Type`argument your class must have a constructor that takes *zero arguments.*

If you insist on using the overload of `Activator.CreateInstance` which only takes the `Type` argument, and not for instance the [overload that takes a collection of objects as `args`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) then you must implement a parameterless constructor.

Example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass() // <-- parameterless constructor
    {
    }
}
```

If the class is not part of your code, or in a library where you don't have control over the source code. Then you might be able to inherit the class, provided the base class is not `sealed` and  then add a `parameterless constructor` to your derived class.

Example:

```
public class MyClass : SomeBaseClassYouDontControl
{
    public MyClass() : base(null) // <-- still a parameterless constructor
    {
    }
}
```

However, i would *advice against* using `Activator.CreateInstance` because of its terrible performance, it is a bit better now than in previous versions of C# / .NET. @SchlaWiener's answer contains much more information about this.

This question, might also be relevant to your question. [Activator.CreateInstance Performance Alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432026/activator-createinstance-performance-alternative)

Comment: There is nothing to say "[...] your class must have a constructor that takes zero arguments." - what about the [override which takes constructor arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm assuming OP is using the overload of Activator.CreateInstance that only takes the `Type`-argument. But i will add information to my post.