# Pre compiled lambda expression to create class that has a constructor with a parameter

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-expressions

I am currently using `Activator.CreateInstance` to create an instance of class whose type is passed in as a generic parameter. The problem is, this is awfully slow. I read somewhere that I could do the same thing using a pre compiled lambda expression, however, I am having trouble implementing this in my case due to a parameter needing to be passed to the instance of the class being created.

Currently I am doing the following

```
public class Class1
{
    private int TestVariable;

    public Class1(int testVariable)
    {
        TestVariable = testVariable;
    }

    public void TestMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Test Variable was {TestVariable}");
    }
}

public object Test<T>(params object[] parameters)
{
    var instance = (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), BindingFlags.Instance, null, new object[] {9999}, null);

    var testMethod = typeof(T).GetMethod("TestMethod", BindingFlags.Instance);

    return testMethod.Invoke(instance, parameters)
}
```

How could I accomplish something similar to this using a pre compiled lambda expression?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activator.CreateInstance Performance Alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432026/activator-createinstance-performance-alternative)

Comment: Don't really see how my question is related to much of that post. I'm looking for specific assistance for an expression lambda that can handle a parameter

Comment: `Don't really see how my question is related to much of that post.` And yet the answer you accepted is **basically the same** as one of the solutions shown in the duplicate...

Comment: @mjwills: The answer is maybe analogous, however the _question_ is definitely different.

Comment: We'll have to agree to disagree on that @Vlad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, using `Expression.Compile` is going to be *slower* if you need to create only *one* object. However if you cache the creator function, it's going to be faster in the long run, as lambda performance will be good.

Here is the code:

```
static Func<TArg, T> CreateCreator<TArg, T>()
{
    var constructor = typeof(T).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(TArg) });
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TArg), "p");
    var creatorExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TArg, T>>(
        Expression.New(constructor, new Expression[] { parameter }), parameter);
    return creatorExpression.Compile();
}
```

```
Func<TArg, T> creator = CreateCreator<TArg, T>();
```

Having this, you can use `creator(arg)` for creating new objects of `T`.

---

Small benchmark of the three ways:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // warm up
        Test1<Class1>(0);
        Test2<int, Class1>(0);

        const int numiter = 10000;
        var sw1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < numiter; i++)
            Test1<Class1>(i);
        sw1.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"With Activator.CreateInstance: " +
            $"{(double)sw1.ElapsedTicks / numiter} ticks per object");

        var sw2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < numiter; i++)
            Test2<int, Class1>(i);
        sw2.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine($"With Expression.Compile: " +
            $"{(double)sw2.ElapsedTicks / numiter} ticks per object");

        var sw3 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var creator = CreateCreator<int, Class1>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numiter; i++)
            creator(i);
        sw3.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine($"With cached Expression.Compile: " +
            $"{(double)sw3.ElapsedTicks / numiter} ticks per object");
    }

    static public object Test1<T>(params object[] parameters)
    {
        var instance = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(
            typeof(T), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, parameters, null);
        return instance;
    }

    static Func<TArg, T> CreateCreator<TArg, T>()
    {
        var constructor = typeof(T).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(TArg) });
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TArg), "p");
        var creatorExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TArg, T>>(
            Expression.New(constructor, new Expression[] { parameter }), parameter);
        return creatorExpression.Compile();
    }

    static public object Test2<TArg, T>(TArg arg)
    {
        var creator = CreateCreator<TArg, T>();
        return creator(arg);
    }
}
```

produces the following result on my machine (release mode/outside Visual Studio):

```
With Activator.CreateInstance: 3.0739 ticks per object
With Expression.Compile: 494.0388 ticks per object
With cached Expression.Compile: 0.1097 ticks per object
```

Comment: Is that basically the same approach as https://stackoverflow.com/a/53959282/34092 ?

Comment: @mjwills: I didn't dig through the whole of that code, bbut the approach (create and cache the creator) seems to be the same.

Comment: @mjwills: the primary goal of the answer is to show the syntax for calling a constructor with parameters.

Comment: To create different types via this approach, is it necessary to repeat the compiled lambda expression for each type? Or there's a way to reuse just one by somehow passing a `Type` argument?

Comment: @mireazma: No, you’ll need to recreate the creator. There is no possibility of generic constructor call except using (perhaps indirectly) `Activator.CreateInstance`.