# Pros and cons for factory method with Activator.CreateInstance and static abstract interface?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

When writing a factory method, I can use either `Activator.CreateInstance` or an interface with static abstract method as follows.

Are there pros and cons I have to consider here?

### With `Activator.CreateInstance`

```cs
using System;

var s = Factory<Student>("Anton");
s?.Print();

var t = Factory<Teacher>("Howard");
t?.Print();



Person? Factory<T>(string name)
    where T : Person
{
    return (T?)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), name);
}


class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Person(string name) => Name = name;
    public void Print() => Console.WriteLine(Name);
}

class Student : Person
{
    public Student(string name) : base($"Student: {name}") { }
}

class Teacher : Person
{
    public Teacher(string name) : base($"Teacher: {name}") { }
}
```

### With static abstract interface

```cs
using System;

var s = Factory<Student>("Anton");
s.Print();

var t = Factory<Teacher>("Howard");
t.Print();

Person Factory<T>(string name)
    where T : Person, IPerson<T>
{
    return T.Constructor(name);
}

interface IPerson<T>
{
    static abstract T Constructor(string name);
}

class Person : IPerson<Person>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Person(string name) => Name = name;
    public void Print() => Console.WriteLine(Name);
    public static Person Constructor(string name) => new(name);
}

class Student : Person, IPerson<Student>
{
    public Student(string name) : base($"Student: {name}") { }
    static Student IPerson<Student>.Constructor(string name) => new(name);
}

class Teacher : Person, IPerson<Teacher>
{
    public Teacher(string name) : base($"Teacher: {name}") { }
    static Teacher IPerson<Teacher>.Constructor(string name) => new(name);
}
```

Comment: As an asside: is there any chance, you create a `Person` that is neither a `Student` nor a `Teacher`? If not, you should make `Person` an `abstract` class.

Comment: Interface-based static Factory Method provides more flexibility if you have some pre/post construction routines ... The generic one with Activator is just a thin wrapper

Comment: Also with the interface you detect changes in the constructor signature on compile time i.e instantaneously, With Activator only at runtime, and sometimes never at all

Comment: The question seem to be opinion based as I would prefer using pre compiled lambda for multiple instantiation of a type https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55137619/pre-compiled-lambda-expression-to-create-class-that-has-a-constructor-with-a-par

Comment: Appendum for @MakePeaceGreatAgain abstract comment: and set name as a constructor parameter. That's basically what you are doing just the proper way :)

Comment: The main difference is who responsible for object construction. Static method is defined in class, so object creates itself. With separate factory object creation delegated to the factory, which can also be abstracted.

Comment: The other reason is perf. `Activator.CreateInstance` and `new()` constraint use reflection under the hood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both appraoches are IMHO bad design, as they completey omit what generics are about: type-safety at *compile-time*. So what is the benefit in writing

```
var s = Factory<Student>("Anton");
```

or

```
var s = IPerson<Student>.Create("Anton");
```

over

```
var s = new Student("Anton");
```

?

In all three cases you need to know the type at *compile-time*, so there's no huge difference between these two. The only benefit on your static interface-approach is, that you get compiler-support when changing the signature of your `Constructor`-method. But after all, an interface shouldn't make any assumptions on how to create instances. Interfaces define *functionality*.

A factory on the other hand only makes sense, if you do *not* know the types at compile-time, or if you want to hide them from your client, e.g.:

```
var s = MyFactory.Create(ReadTypeNameFromDatabase(), "Anton");
```

This way the factory decides which type to instantiate.

```
class MyFactory
{
    public static IPerson Create(string typeName, string name)
    {
        return (IPerson) Activator.CreateInstance(typeName, name);
    }
}
```

A client on the other hand just gets an abstraction, i.e. an interface-pointer (`IPerson` for example).

As an asside: it might be a good idea to make `Person` an `abstract` class, so you cannot just create instances of it via `new Person("Anton")`. However it depends on your data-model if that makes sense.

Comment: well, typically factories make use of `Activator.CreateInstance`  as seen in my update. You can provide the `typeName` from a config-file, for example.